# Two columns, left with fixed width, right with dynamic width

Tags: css, html

i am trying to implement a content where i need to have a section of 100% of the browser width and inside it i need to have in the left size a div with 200px width and in it's right i need to have a div with dynamic width depending of the browser width.
Example .. browser = 900px -> left div 200px right div 700px.
And both of the divs have dynamic height depending how much info i put in them .. the wrapper div will take the biggest of those 2 div height..

So far i did something like this 
html

```
<section id="wrapper">
  <div id="list">
  </div>
  <div id="grid">
  </div>
</section>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now i need to css the #list and #grid divs. I hope there is an efficient solution to this because later on i will have the same stuff to do inside the #grid div :)

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it with CSS. The trick is to use a float (the left div) and a non-floating div (the right one). Also the left (floating) div, needs to have a minimum height, otherwise the right (non-floating) div will take the space of the left column if the left doesn't have any content.

EDIT: The right `<div>` should also have the following rules:

```
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
```

The `overflow: hidden` makes the right div behave as a column, otherwise its content would flow around the left div.

Note that the `#wrapper` doesn't need a width because the default width of a `<div>` is 100% (since you said it will take the full width of the browser window), and also remove its margins.

Here's an example (I changed the `<section>` to `<div>` for the sake of the non HTML5 browsers but it works the same).

I placed background colours to distinguish all the elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/pmv3s/1/

Here is the full screen version: http://fiddle.jshell.net/pmv3s/1/show/light/

**The CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    padding: 40px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 5px;
}
#list {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 100px;
}
#grid {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    background-color: blue;  
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

​

Comment: That just creates a floating box with a set height. If the other column's (the right one's) height grows bigger than the left column, the content will float around that box and that box will be displayed as just that. A small box in the top left.

Comment: @Tom true, but the OP didn't ask for same height inner divs, did he? he said `the wrapper div will take the *biggest* of those 2 div height`

Comment: "float around" as in both to the right and below the left box, which is not what the OP's asking for

Comment: @Tom you're right, I forgot to add the `overflow: hidden` to the right div, check my jsfiddle, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: No problem :) ..and thank you for the pure CSS solution ^^ +1

Comment: yep, i have come to a solution which is exactly the same like this one :D thank you very much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution for you using a little bit of jQuery as I don't think that there's a pure CSS solution to your problem (but I may be wrong).

http://fiddle.jshell.net/L32uj/